# ncurses freaks out when writing wide character to certain screen locations

Tags: c++, linux, unicode, terminal, ncurses

I am writing an application using ncurses and wish to use box drawing characters in it, specifically u/2550 and u/2551 (as of now). I have for loops setup to draw bars to two sides of the terminal, based off screen size I determine elsewhere.

For whatever reason when it comes to drawing any unicode characters horizontally (here at the bottom of the screen, but it does this on any row), it will go from printing the characters fine to printing garbage 'P's. This is a bit hard to explain, so I have some pictures showing what happens when I draw 6 characters and then 7 or more characters.

[image: With 6 characters]

[image: With 7 characters]

The part of the code responsible for drawing these characters is as such, note that the last for loop is what draws these characters, and the iterator is supposed to go farther than just 7, but it does this here and anywhere else.

```
void drawBorder(){ //draw the border graphics
                attron(COLOR_PAIR(3));
        for(int i = 1; i < screenSizeY - 1; i++){ //draw left side
                mvaddwstr(i, 0, L"║");
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < screenSizeY - 1; i++){ //draw right side
                mvaddwstr(i, screenSizeX - 1, L"\u2551");
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){ //draw bottom
                mvaddwstr(screenSizeY - 1, i, L"\u2550");
        }
                attroff(COLOR_PAIR(3));
}
```

I am linking against the ncursesw package and have a properly set locale. Other characters drawn in vertical lines work just fine, but it doesn't here. I am using C++ compiled with g++, running on Linux in an Alacritty terminal session.

This has nothing to do with box draw functions, or specific terminal capabilities, all of the wide characters are perfectly supported by the terminal, and work in other parts of the terminal. This will happen based on how many of these I draw in a row, and also happens for other box characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Borders don't draw properly when window has more than 8 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114075/borders-dont-draw-properly-when-window-has-more-than-8-columns)

Comment: Unrelated, my issue has nothing to do with the capabilities of my terminal, although strangely ncurses colour seems to be completely broken on xterm and mate-terminal, something I have also yet to figure out.

This has to do with wide characters not being properly displayed based off a certain screen location. It might even be a bug in ncurses, but I don't trust myself enough to file a bug report for something that could still be user error.

Comment: Possibly the ECMA-48 **REP** (repeat character) control sequence is not working with wide characters.  The ASCII value for 'P' is 0x50, the LSB of your wide border character.

Comment: I had noticed that bit as well, but I find it strange it works fine with smaller numbers of characters, but not longer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OP sent a more complete example, which shows the problem:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    initscr();
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    raw();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        mvaddwstr(0, i, L"\u2550");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        mvaddwstr(1, i, L"\u2550");
    }
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;

}
```

The problem is that the library is initialized with a different locale than is used in the `mvaddwstr` calls.  The [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) says

> The  library uses the locale which the calling program has initialized.
>   That is normally done with **`setlocale`**:
>
> **`setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`**
>
> If the locale is not initialized, the library assumes  that  characters
>   are  printable  as in **ISO-8859-1**, to work with certain legacy programs.
>   You should initialize the locale and not rely on  specific  details  of
>   the library when the locale has not been setup.

Because the call to **`setlocale`** is after **`initscr`**, rather than before, ncurses assumes the data is ISO-8859-1, and runs into an unexpected scenario.  In other places such as `addwstr`, ncurses checks if the data is valid `wchar_t`, but in those, it's using the **current** locale.  In this case, it's far away from the functions that it knows must be handled in that way (it's rendering data which has already been processed).  The comparison in the library which allow this to be handled using the *`repeat_char`* capability can be improved, but the actual bug is in the sample program.

Comment: I thank you so much for that, I knew it should have been something simple, and the explanation makes sense.

Yes, I should have made a better example at the start, but I often don't know what to put in these things, and end up putting snippets of the program the issue is working in instead of creating entirely new example programs, which I should start doing.

Comment: A sample program always helps, because it can be tested (reading a fragment can't do that).

Comment: Yeah I get it. I'm fairly new to serious programming, and almost everything I do is a first for me.