# Ncurses and C++ string concatenation not working properly

Tags: c++, string, ncurses

I'm trying to display a statusbar using ncurses with "---" between items, like most terminal programs do.

I have the following code so far:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <curses.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    initscr();
    start_color();

    init_pair(3, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_RED);

    getch();
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(3));

    string a = "--- Tickets: 455";

    a.append(70, '-');

    mvprintw(LINES-1, 0, a.c_str());

    getch();

    endwin();
}
```

The mvprintw should output the whole width of the screen until the right border. But in fact, only one "-" is appended.

I'm not sure if this is a an ncurses problem or if strings are not converted to c style strings properly. Could someone help me identify the issue?

Comment: I figured out that removing the for loop and append with a.append(5, '-') i get what I want - but if I  append more than 6 characters, only one '-' is appended.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, I get the expected output; but I'm almost positive that you simply need to add a `refresh();` before calling `getch()` the 2nd time. See curses documentation for more information. Maybe my version of curses has `getch`()` automatically flush everything out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Borders don't draw properly when window has more than 8 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114075/borders-dont-draw-properly-when-window-has-more-than-8-columns).  It's been a couple of years, but some developers were slow to followup on their bug.

Comment: I figured out that this has to do with my TERM variable. In fact I use "st" as terminal - so what would be the proper term variable then?